# Angular loop over reactive form controls from HTML

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a HTML table that is creating a TR component based on an `ngFor` loop.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let t of intakeForm.controls['tasks'].value let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex" [taskTR]="t" [ui]="uiOptions" [tasks]="configuredTasks" [intakeForm]="intakeForm"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Currently, I am looping over the value of the form for these controls but I am trying to loop over the controls instead so I can pass them to the `tr`component.

**Something like:**

`let t of intakeForm.controls['tasks'].controls`

`tasks` is a form array and I am trying to loop over the array of controls it has so that I can pass it to the component.

I tried this `let t of (<FormArray>intakeForm.controls['tasks'].controls)` but it didn't work. Not sure that it can be done within the html like that.

End goal here is that I want to pass the form control on each iteration to the `tr` component.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `get` method within form groups to inspect specific controls. It's a much cleaner way of accessing controls within form groups.

Also using the methodology below allows you to "drop" into each element within the array and access the properties directly within your template since you are already "within" the correct formGroup in the FormArray. So no need for long prefixes with indices to define which element of the FormArray you are working on.

```
<ng-container formArrayName="tasks">
    <tr [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let task of intakeForm.get('tasks').controls; let i=index">
        <input type="text" formControlName="taskName" />
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, this looks like it will work, wasn't aware of `get` on the forms

Comment: Yep, its really handy component-side as well.